# Displaying search results crashes when using UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I tried to implement a SearchBarView Controller to my TableView with CoreData. But, when I tap on the Searchbar, the app crashes and I get the following Error:

> Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:5439
>   `***` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Without Searchbar I show my TableContent like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.inventory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"productName"]]];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"company"]];

    return cell;
}
```

works perfectly.

So now I tried to show the SearchbarViewControllerContent like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {device = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];}
    else
        {device = [self.cart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; }

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"productName"]]];

    return cell;
}
```

but this doesn't work.

If you have to know how my Searchbar (should) works:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 71;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [cartProducts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assertion failure when using UISearchDisplayController in UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207142/assertion-failure-when-using-uisearchdisplaycontroller-in-uitableviewcontroller)

Comment: same problem, but different approaches

Comment: Has Anyone another Solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "another solution"? Which solutions did you try from the answers to the duplicate question? Why did they not work?

Comment: I'm sorry... Okay so i worked trough the duplicate Topic and solved the Problem with the crashing App. But when i type a letter in the search bar returns "No Results". How can i be sure, that the search bar is searching in my CoreData? Or has this "No Results"-Error nothing to do with it?

Comment: That's a different question, so better post a new one ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the cell for search tableView in viewDidLoad method  such as:

```
  [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:<Nib Name> bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:<cellIdentifier>]
```