# Search Bar Inconsistency Error (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I  am trying to hook up a search bar that is inside a view above my table view:

```
//Outlet for the table search bar/controller
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var searchController =  UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var searchBar_optional = false

//Function for when the search button is triggered
@IBAction func searchButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if(searchBar_optional == false){
         tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: barView.bounds.size.height-30, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
        searchBar_optional = true
    }
    else if (searchBar_optional){
         tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: barView.bounds.size.height-78, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
        searchBar_optional = false
    }

}

var dataArray = [MainTableViewCell]()

var filteredArray = [MainTableViewCell]()

var shouldShowSearchResults = false


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
    filteredArray = dataArray.filter{ cell in
        if((cell.fileName.text?.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)) == true){
            return true
        }
        else if((cell.fileDescription.text?.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)) == true){
            return true
        }
        else if((cell.fileCategory.text?.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)) == true){
            return true
        }
        else if((cell.fileType.text?.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)) == true){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!)
}

func configureSearchController() {
 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
 definesPresentationContext = true

}
```

It moves down the view when the search button is pressed, making the search bar visible. However, when I press the search bar, this error pops up:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-
3512.60.7/UITableView.m:6573
2016-08-02 13:13:05.001 References[22478:14561725] *** Terminating app due 
to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to
dequeue a cell with identifier MainTableCell - must register a nib or a 
class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

My cell identifier for my cells is MainTableCell, so that is why it says that in the error. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Have you registered your nib file with the UITableView ?

Comment: @tek3 yes. The table view works fine, the only error occurs when I click inside the search bar

Comment: See if this link helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207142/assertion-failure-when-using-uisearchdisplaycontroller-in-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: Can You show us code related to tableView also? Maybe I am wrong, but my intuition still tell me it is problem with some table view.

Comment: I also updated my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't register tableViewCell with this identifier. Put `MainTableCell` in cell id in Storyboard or where You register cell class for tableView (if You do it programmatically).

**Update:**

I think it is related to dequeuing cell from tableView.
I guess You have standard code:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Please, try this replace this with:

```
cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: I did register it. The error is not with the table view, it is when I click inside the search bar